# center a rectangle to the midpoint

Tags: add-on

Using the CAD Sketcher addon.
When creating a new sketch, and adding a rectangle:

[image]

Then what are the different ways to center this rectangle to the midpoint?
( Often called `SlvsPoint2D(0)` )

https://www.cadsketcher.com/

Comment: For example: right-click on the object, _Set Origin_ > _Origin to Geometry_. Then press Alt+G to reset the location to the world center.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That doesn't work well with this addon. As soon as a Update happens with the solver engine, then things will shift to where they where.

Comment: I thought you would want to center this in Blender. Is this is a question about the external addon, it's not suitable for this site, you should rather ask the addon developers.

Answer (score 1):

Make a line the goes from one corner vertex to the opposite corner vertex. Make it construction. Select the line and plane center point. Set a midpoint constraint.

[image]

(thanks to rainbowfox)